# Como posso concluir essa função no Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Não consigo chegar na 
solução da questão! Não estou conseguindo apresentar na tela a solução completa! (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uE45.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diego, se compreendi bem, uma das formas de implementar essa função é a seguinte:

```js
function retornaEnderecoUsuario(endereco) {
  return 'O usuário mora em ' + endereco.cidade + ' / ' + endereco.uf + ', no bairro ' + endereco.bairro + ', na rua "' + endereco.rua + '" com nº ' + endereco.numero + ".";
}

var endereco = {
  rua: "Rua dos pinheiros",
  numero: 1293,
  bairro: "Centro",
  cidade: "São Paulo",
  uf: "SP"
}

var informacoesEndereco = retornaEnderecoUsuario(endereco);

console.log(informacoesEndereco);
```

A concatenação de string também pode ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
function retornaEnderecoUsuario(endereco) {
  return `O usuário mora em ${endereco.cidade} / ${endereco.uf}, no bairro ${endereco.bairro}, na rua "${endereco.rua}" com nº ${endereco.numero}.`;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo!